Problems with setting up ElasticSearch and Filebeat on Ubuntu Server
This is my first time posting here, so bear with me.
I'm trying to set up a homelab for myself, but have encountered issues with configuring ElasticSearch and Filebeat.
ES kept dying (i.e. failing with exit-code) until I changed the network.host to 0.0.0.0; for clarity, the IP of that virtual machine is 192.168.1.68.
Now, regardless of whether I use 0.0.0.0, 192.168.1.68, 192.168.1.0, or 192.168.0.0 in the hosts of output.elasticsearch (in the Filebeat.yml file), if I try running a curl command (e.g. curl "http://192.168.1.68:9200"), I keep getting a curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a connection.  response.
Similarly, if I run
/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat setup -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml --path.data /var/lib/filebeat --path.home /usr/share/filebeat

I get a Couldn't connect to any of the configured ElasticSearch hosts. response.
For authentication (since I'm still at the initial stages) in Filebeat, I'm using the elastic superuser and a password I generated.
Which host am I supposed to set up in the elasticsearch.yml and filebeat.yml files?
(I'm also new to Linux in general, fwiw. )

Can you try curl -k https://192.168.1.68:9200/_cat/health?pretty?
also please check the elasticsearch logs.

This ended up pointing me in the right direction. It seems the Kibana.yml file was conflicting with the filebeat.yml one; once I consolidated them, everything ran smoothly. I've sorted it out now and have everything set up. Thank you!

Amazing. Happy to hear it solved! Let me write this as an answer.

Please mark as an answer.

You can check the elasticsearch health with curl -k https://localhost:9200/_cat/health?pretty?
Also check the elasticsearch logs, and make sure it works fine.
You're using HTTP curl requests. Elasticsearch v8 and onwards comes with HTTPS by default.
